# telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError

Tags: telethon

The first time I touched Telethon, I changed the api_id and api_hash, and then ran the program, but the following error was reported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scraper.py", line 370, in
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
File "/root/.miniconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "scraper.py", line 41, in main
await init_empty()
File "scraper.py", line 187, in init_empty
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
File "/root/.miniconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/requestiter.py", line 74, in anext
if await self._load_next_chunk():
File "/root/.miniconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/dialogs.py", line 53, in _load_next_chunk
r = await self.client(self.request)
File "/root/.miniconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in call
return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
File "/root/.miniconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 84, in _call
result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetDialogsRequest)
```

May I ask what modifications I need to make to run this program(https://github.com/edogab33/telegram-groups-crawler)? Do I need a Telegram group file? Can you provide a simple example? Thank you.

Comment: You have to use a userbot (api_id, api_hash, phone) client. The error you are facing is because you are using a bot account and the API for bots is limited.